# linq to sql optimized a group with multiple joins

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, group-by

I need help generating a more efficient LINQ query:

```
Table: Positions
-PositionID
-Name

Table: Person
-PersonID
-Name, etc...

Table: PersonPosition
-PersonID
-PositionID
```

I need a result set that groups the people assigned to each position:

```
PositionID  Person
1           John
            Bob
            Frank

2           Bill
            Tom
            Frank, etc...
```

My first thought was this LINQ query:

```
from perspos in PersonPositions
join pers in Persons            on perspos.PersonID equals pers.PersonID 
group pers by perspos.PositionID into groups
select new {groups.Key, groups}
```

Which works great, but produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT [t0].[PositionID] AS [Key]
FROM [PersonPosition] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [Person] AS [t1] ON [t0].[PersonID] = [t1].[PersonID]
GROUP BY [t0].[PositionID]
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @x1 Int = 3
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t1].[PersonID], [t1].[UserID], [t1].[Firstname], [t1].[Lastname], [t1].[Email], [t1].[Phone], [t1].[Mobile], [t1].[Comment], [t1].[Permissions]
FROM [PersonPosition] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [Person] AS [t1] ON [t0].[PersonID] = [t1].[PersonID]
WHERE @x1 = [t0].[PositionID]
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @x1 Int = 4
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t1].[PersonID], [t1].[UserID], [t1].[Firstname], [t1].[Lastname], [t1].[Email], [t1].[Phone], [t1].[Mobile], [t1].[Comment], [t1].[Permissions]
FROM [PersonPosition] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [Person] AS [t1] ON [t0].[PersonID] = [t1].[PersonID]
WHERE @x1 = [t0].[PositionID]
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @x1 Int = 5
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t1].[PersonID], [t1].[UserID], [t1].[Firstname], [t1].[Lastname], [t1].[Email], [t1].[Phone], [t1].[Mobile], [t1].[Comment], [t1].[Permissions]
FROM [PersonPosition] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [Person] AS [t1] ON [t0].[PersonID] = [t1].[PersonID]
WHERE @x1 = [t0].[PositionID]
GO

on and on...
```

Is there a better LINQ query that translates to a more efficient SQL statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should already have the relationship defined in your database, and also on your dbml.

Avoid doing joins when you don't have to; they are really tedious.  Let LINQ-to-SQL do this for you.  Something like this should work:

```
var data = context.PersonPositions
    .Select(pos => new { pos.PositionID, pos.Person });
return data.GroupBy(pos => pos.PositionID);
```

or

```
return context.Positions.Select(pos => 
    new { pos, pos.PersonPositions.Select(pp => pp.Person).ToList() }).ToList();
```

Comment: I have a one-to-many relation setup from Person -> PersonPosition, but not the other way.  Having trouble adding that relationship, I'm getting "the columns in table PersonPosition do not match any existing primary key or unique constraint".  I cant make PersonPosition's PersonID a PK or unique index because it's the intermediate in my many-to-many relationship in Person-PersonPosition-Position, so there will be multiple records with the same PersonID

Comment: Do you have a primary key on the `PersonPosition` table at all?  You can either create a surrogate PK (`PersonPositionId`) or make a composite out of both PersonId and PositionId, but you will need a primary key of some sort for LINQ-to-SQL to handle it.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I have a composite primary key of (PersonID, PositionID) on PersonPositions table, but still get that same error.  I'm allowing nulls for PersonID in both tables, would that cause it?

Comment: Well that might cause something - SQL doesn't let you have a nullable PK, whether it's a single column or a composite, so I don't know!  Check that the PKs are still on the tables, and that they show up on the dbml designer.  The columns should be non nullable in the database, and the dbml should also reflect this (in the properties viewer)

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure you have to just join the tables and select the result, then call .AsEnumerable(), and group after that:

```
(from perspos in PersonPositions
 join pers in Persons
 on perspos.PersonID equals pers.PersonID
 select new { perspos.PositionID, Person = pers })
.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(p => p.PositionID, p => p.Person);
```